# Javascript Animation - Math

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I have a question about animations in JS. I don't know how the others libraries do the animations, but I have seen one with `setTimeout()` which could be pretty easy. But I'm a bit confused in math. Let's say, I want to animate height of element (using "pure" javascript) from **80px** to **240px**. So I need to get first the current height of element `parseInt(element.style.height, 10)` - this should return just a numeric value without **px**. Or use `getComputedStyle()` or whatever. So now I need to calculate difference between initial height and final height. So it's **160px**. Now I want to set animation duration to **2000ms**.

**The question:** How do I calculate timeout for this animation and the "step" height (the height I will add to last height when the `setTimeout` is called) ?

Code:

```
function animate( elem, height, time ) {
    var initHeight = parseInt(elem.style.height, 10);
    /* var styles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
       var initHeight = styles.getPropertyValue('height'); */

    var diffHeight = ( initHeight > height ? ( initHeight - height ) :
    (( initHeight != height ) ? ( height - initHeight ) : false ) );

    var stepHeight = ????? height to be added ???????
    var duration = ????? duration of timeout ??????

    var lastHeight = initHeight;
    animation();
    function animation () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            lastHeight += stepHeight;
            elem.style.height = lastHeight + 'px';

            if ( lastHeight < height ) { animation(); }
            else { elem.style.height = height + 'px'; }  // set required value if is exceeded
        }, duration);
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById('square');
animate( el, 240, 2000 );
```

**PS:** I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: Why not adding CSS `transition` property to element and then setting CSS styles with JS? :)

Comment: Either you want to use a *constant speed* animation, in which you increase the size by a fixed amount every fixed number of (milli)seconds, in which case you simply keep doing that until the height is reached. Or you want to increase the height every x (milli)seconds by enough that the final height will be reached after a fixed amount of animation steps. In that case it's simply `increaseBy = heightDifference / animationSteps`.

Comment: Because I'm more interested in JS than CSS3. What can be done with CSS I do, but animation comes to me in CSS unnatural :D

Comment: one pixel every 2000/160 is ... 12,5 ms or if you like for every 2px wait 25 ms.

Comment: I don't want to use constant speed. Because I want to set animation time and it depends on speed. .. thanks Nina Scholz :)

Comment: then it depends on the speed, how it accelerate.

Comment: Behold, I made [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub9wh8sz/) for you :P You really don't need JS calculation, it's slow...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this:

Also `setTimeout` will run after specified delay. `setInterval` will loop function with specific delay. But with `setInterval`, You should keep caution to clear it on a threshold limit.

You can control smoothness with `speed`. I have reduced speed to `10ms`

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/33yjjx2g/1/)

```js
function animate( elem, height, speed, duration ) {
   var limit = duration/speed;
   var heightIncrement = (height - elem.clientHeight)/limit;
   var count = 0;
   
   var anim_interval = setInterval(function(){
    var h = parseFloat(elem.style.height || elem.clientHeight);
    elem.style.height = (h + heightIncrement) + "px";
    if(count++>=limit)
     window.clearInterval(anim_interval)
   }, speed)
}

var el = document.getElementById('square');
animate( el, 240, 10, 2000 );
```

```css
.square {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="square" class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more smooth?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can control smoothness with speed.

Comment: You should also look into [Request Animation Frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). For animations, this is more preferred than `setTimeout` or `setInterval`